# How to use bash to get a web page and parse the specified line?

Tags: bash, shell

Our software password is stored in a web page, and likes this:

```
Last month: suilwoid 
This month: suewkhud 
Next month: guenkhid
```

I want to write a `Bash` script to get the password of this month, and the simple script likes this:

```
wget http://passwd.xxx.com/~perf/passwd.php &
wait

echo `grep "This month" passwd.php | awk '{ print $3 }'`
```

This script can meet my requirement, but I want to know how to implement this script more elegantly.

For example, whether can use pipeline to concatenate the commands? Except the `awk`, are there any better commands to parse the password?

Comment: `&` and `wait` seems unnecessary, why do you use them? And you could let `wget` write to STDOUT and `grep` it directly instead of saving to a file.

Comment: @Biffen: Yeah, & and wait are unnecessary.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `--output-document` option of `wget` to write the file to standard output, then process that.

Normally, the documents are created on disk with similar names to the originals but you can use `--output-document=blah` to concatenate them all into a single file called `blah`. And, if that file name you specify is `-`, that means send it to standard output instead.

So something like the following (on one line) should suffice:

```
wget --quiet --output-document=- http://passwd.xxx.com/~perf/passwd.ph
   | awk '/This month/ {print $3}'
```

The `--quiet` option prevents `wget` from outputting its normal stuff such as status information and progress. Currently this goes to standard error so wouldn't be included in the pipeline to `awk` but I'll put it there because:

1. It's generally better to be quiet than noisy.
2. I can't guarantee `wget` will always behave the way it currently does.

You'll notice there's also no need for a separate `grep` in the pipeline since `awk` can do the same thing with its selectors.

Comment: Shouldn't you use `-q` as well as awk will look through the normal output of wget as well ?

Comment: @JID, the normal output of `wget` currently goes to standard error which won't be used by the pipeline, but I'll add that as an option.

Comment: @paxdiablo: "Currently this goes to standard output ...", should be "standard error", right?